# Syntax error near unexpected token `('

Tags: cardano-node

I'm trying to set up a Cardano-node using the steps on [this](https://cardano-node-installation.stakepool247.eu/v/cardano-node-1.30.1/cardano-node-installation-process) web site but I am running into errors regarding the .bashrc file on line 122 If any of you know How to fix this it would be much appreciated.

here's my code https://gist.github.com/FloofyFlare/8f6303830ab9978950f30f28908bd03d

Comment: Do you really need to build it from source code?

Comment: Have a look at your users .bashrc file on line 122.  If you still can't figure out the error then you will have to post the actual error message and the contents of your .bashrc file so that someone can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I got the `/home/_____/.bashrc` directory mixed up because I did not adapt the name of the user to my situation, as I was following a tutorial. Thanks for the help.